# how do you open the candy box

Tags: candy-box-2

I have tried and tried to open the candy box but it won't work I have all four stones whats my problem?

Comment: Have you placed all the stones in the tower?

Comment: yesss i have placed them

Comment: Did you take the candy that appeared?